# ListView at the bottom of my Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

basically I have layout with some views (TextView, editText and buttons) that almost filling  the screen and the bottom of these views I have ListVew element. 
I'm populating this list on run time.The problem I have that the scrolling of the listView is not working.I tried to have scrolling bar on the whole layout and it did not work.
What is the best way to have listview at the end of your layout?

regards,
red sea

Answer (score 1):

> Never put **listview,mapview,Webview** in scrollview because these views already have scrolling.

I think other view like textview,imageview put in RelativeLayout and this Relativelayout put in scrollview.and complete the tag of scrollview `</ScrollView>` .now You should add listview below scrollView.

Like.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll" ...>
 <RelativeLayout...>
  <TextView... />
  <TextView... />
  <ImageView... />
 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ListView android:layout_below="@+id/@+id/scroll"... />
```